# I need to select newest rows from a MySQL database, but verify that I am also returning a row with a given ID

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to this, sorry if the title is confusing. I am building a simple php/mysql gallery of sorts. It will show the newest 25 entries when a user first goes to it, and also allows off-site linking to individual items in the list. If the URL contains an ID, javascript will scroll to it. But if there are 25+ entries, it's possible that my query will fetch the newest results, but omit an older entry that happens to be in the URL as an ID.

That means I need to do something like this...

```
SELECT * FROM `submissions` WHERE uid='$sid'
```

But after that has successfully found the submission with the special ID, also do

```
SELECT * FROM `submissions`  ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0, 25`
```

So that I can populate the rest of the gallery.

I could query that database twice, but I am assuming there's some nifty way to avoid that. MySQL is also ordering everything (based on newest, views, and other vars) and using two queries would break that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could limit across a UNION like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM submissions WHERE uid = '$uid')
UNION
(SELECT * FROM submissions WHERE uid <> '$uid' ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 25)
LIMIT 25
```

Note `LIMIT` is listed twice as in the case that the first query returns a result, we would have 26 results in the union set.  This will also place the "searched for" item first in the returned sort result set (with the other 24 results displayed in sort order).  If this is not desirable, you could place an `ORDER BY` across the union, but your searched for result would be truncated if it happened to be the 26th record.

If you need 25 rows with all of them being sorted, my guess is that you would need to do the two query approach (limiting second query to either 24 or 25 records depending on whether the first query matched), and then simply insert the uid-matched result into the sorted records in the appropriate place before display.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better solution is:

```
SELECT *
FROM `submissions`
order by (case when usid = $sid then 0 else 1 end),
         id desc
limit 25
```

I don't think the `union` is guaranteed to return results in the order of the union (there is no guarantee in the standard or in other databases).